# Legends of tomorrow quote, what is it from?

Tags: dialogue, legends-of-tomorrow, arrowverse

This quote sounds awfully familiar, but I cannot figure out, why. Anyone knows if this is a reference to some other move? Sounds starwarsish ...

> Rip: "I vowed to save my family, but I'm failing them. Perhaps I'm not the Time Master they need."
>
> Stein: "You must be. You're the only one they have."

Comment: Sound more Doctor Who-y to me. (And it's fun to say "Doctor Who-y".)

Comment: The Dark Knight? "Because he's the hero Gotham deserves, but not the one it needs right now."

Comment: It seems there could be a trope based on this general concept. A 'the only hero they have'.. type of thing.

Comment: I thought this might have been the one question my "Official Quotable Doctor Who" would help answering, but alas, no. I do think the writers are having an awful lot of fun making Rory say Time Lord-y things, but this is just a general allusion.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that this is a direct quote from any other media. However, it is reminiscent of a quote about Batman (another DC Comics superhero) from *The Dark Knight*:

> "He's the hero Gotham deserves, but not the one it needs right now." —Commissioner Gordon

In both quotes, the hero is said to not be the one that the people need, but the one they have got anyway.

This may just be a coincidence though, as it is a fairly common trope for the hero to doubt that they are the one that the people need. For instance, Oliver Queen has had these doubts many times on *Arrow*. Stein's response is a typical response of ["You are better than you think you are"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouAreBetterThanYouThinkYouAre) (warning: TV Tropes link), saying that the hero must be the one to save the day.